# awk in while loop not working

Tags: bash, awk, while-loop

I am trying the following command:

```
while read file
do
awk -v ID="$file" '$1==ID{print $0}' input2 > output
done < input1
```

input1 looks like this:

```
1
2
3
4
```

input2 looks like this:

```
2 a b c
3 a b c
5 a b c
6 a b c
```

The output should look like this:

```
3 a b c
```

So, in other words, if the first column of file input2 matches one of the values from file input1, I want the whole line from input2 printed to output. My while loop from above only produces empty files however... What could be the problem? Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Output is destroyed at each iteration
Use >> instead of > or only last iteration shows

Answer (score 3):

Don't do that, it's immensely inefficient and fragile (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice). Do this instead:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ids[$0];next} $1 in ids' input1 input2 > output
```

Comment: +1! Until recently I was thinking that awk could only handle one input file. I think most people ignore that too, hence the `while read` construction.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately many people think of awk as just a fancy grep or sed. It's far more than that, though - it's **the** standard UNIX general purpose text processing tool. I always recommend anyone who might have to manipulate text in UNIX read Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins first. It'll probably be a game changer.

Comment: Definitely, although it's becoming a bit old fashioned now that we have python. BTW could you explain your oneliner? People will use multiple input streams more if they understand how it works.

Comment: "**now** that we have python"? Python has been around for a quarter of a century, it hasn't and won't make awk look old fashioned in any way. Also it's no more a peer for awk than awk is a peer for sed - awk is for manipulating text, period. What I posted is absolutely basic awk, all well explained (along with many other equally useful features) in the book Effective Awk programming, 4th Edition by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: you're right, it was based on my rather recent usage (10 years) of python which made me stop coding in awk completely. Primarily opinion based to say the least. awk has its limits & crashes when the size of the line is too big (40000+ chars, I solved such a awk question recently by proposing a python alternative) but in that case, can we consider the file as a text file or disguised binary?

Comment: You're probably thinking of the very old and unfortunately named `nawk`, I doubt if any modern awk would have that problem with a text file. I'm actually not sure what the criteria is to identify a file as "binary" but if it contains ASCII characters and ends in a newline it's a text file while if it doesn't end in a newline then, ASCII content or not, it's not a POSIX text file and so invites nasal demons when you try to run a UNIX tool on it. If you'd like to provide a URL for the question in question I'd be happy to take a look.